# Hybris WCMS "how to add a store location" Integration with google maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud, liveedit

I want to integrate "Product Availability by Store Location" in wcms cockpit-Hybris , the objective is to locate the product store pickup in google maps.

How to integrate with the help of backoffice?

[image]

and what to write in the owner when adding a new region in backoffice

[image]

Comment: I have added two images one is Store locator in my storefront and the other is of backoffice where I am unable to enter the owner!! how would be the owner and how to add the store address so that it will show in the available stores related to the products ..urgent Thanks In Advance